# How to change React Native TextInput cursor color (not selectionColor)

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput

`selectionColor` only changes the vertical bar color, not the cursor color you see when you're dragging/selecting the text. Screenshot below.

I found some answers which suggested modifying `styles.xml`, but I'm using Expo so that's not possible for me(?). Is there any other way to do it?

[image: TextInput wrong cursor color on Android]

Comment: I think the only way to that with expo, is to eject your project to bare workflow. And then you can change it from native side.